# Programming the MK20DX256VLH7 with Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, arm, teensy

I want to start using the [MK20DX256VLH7](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pjrc.com%2Fteensy%2FK20P64M72SF1.pdf&ei=9oKeVdGaDYqSsgGIlZnoDg&usg=AFQjCNFhWVqEcGphaYO0P76gcidqh28mzA&sig2=O4d2w8kNCnhfxz39vrXPBw) in my projects. This is going to be my first 32bit microcontroller. I love the simplicity of the Arduino IDE and I would like to keep using it with this microcontroller.

I found the [Teensy 3.1](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12646) board that already use this micro and it is possible to program the board using the Arduino IDE, BUT, it use a **non open source bootloader** inside a mini54tan microcontroller ([schematics](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/schematic.html)).

I understand that the author does not want the board to be cloned, but that is not my goal. When I use my 8bits microcontroller, the atmega328p, I have it on my breadboard using just the minimal components and an [arduino board programmed as ISP programmer](http://www.htlinux.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/arduino_programmer.png). In this way I can still use the Arduino IDE and program the 328 with no bootloader on so I can use the complete memory of the microcontroller.

I want to do the same with the MK20DX256VLH7 (I know is SMD, im going to build an adapter). Can I use the same principal? Is the arduino board programmed as programmer capable of writing code to this microcontroller, do I have to make huge changes to the Arduino IDE in order to make this work, or I can just use the [Teensy arduino mod](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_download.html)?

Comment: "I love the simplicity of the Arduino IDE" - You should HATE it for this. Use the dedicated tools, really.

Comment: You should consider using a more advance IDE if you want to use  a 32 bits MCU, also using a JTAG probe is a pretty efficient way to programm a MCU.